# Use optimize() for a function which returns several values

Tags: r

Easier to ask by example. If I have a function

```
fn <- function(x) {
...
return(c(a,b,c))
}
```

and I wish to maximize (or minimize) with respect to `a`, but also get the values of `b` and `c` at the optimal value.

Of course I can use `fn2 <- function(x) fn(x)[1]` to determine the optimal value, then call the function again, but I wonder if there is a smarter way of doing this.

Comment: I doubt it. `optimize` is already calling the function a bunch of times to find the desired value. One more call shouldn't be that inefficient. Plus it expects `f` to only return one value, otherwise it is unclear how to compare values to know if progress is being made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`optim` needs the return value to be a scalar.  The documentation says so

```
  fn: A function to be minimized (or maximized), with first
      argument the vector of parameters over which minimization is
      to take place.  It should return a scalar result.
```

You could write the values of interest to a global variable inside your function though.  This isn't necessarily best practice but it could work.

```
f <- function(x){
  .vals <<- c(x, x+1)
  x^2
}
optim(1, f)
```

then after we can look at what is stored in `.vals`

```
> .vals
[1] 9.765625e-05 1.000098e+00
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I am currently doing, just that I don't like mixing environments. Thanks!